# Getting a JSON from the Task

Tags: json, swift, url

So I know how to parse JSON and retrieve a JSON from a URLRequest. What my objective is to remove this JSON file so I can manipulate it into different UIViewControllers. I have seen some stuff with completion handlers but I run into some issues, and I haven't fully understand. I feel like there is a simple answer, I am just being dumb.

How can I take this JSON outside the task and use it in other Swift files as a variable?

```
class ShuttleJson: UIViewController{

func getGenres(completionHandler: @escaping (_ genres: [String: Any]) -> ()) {

let urlstring = "_________"
let urlrequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlstring)!)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let sessions = URLSession(configuration: config)

// request part
let task = sessions.dataTask(with: urlrequest) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("error getting data")
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("error, did not receive data")
        return
    }
    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any]{

            //Something should happen here
        }
        print("no json sucks")
    }
    catch{
        print("nah")
    }
}
task.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the underscore and the parameter label from the completion handler. Both are useless

```
func getGenres(completionHandler: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> ()) {
```

---

Then replace the line

```
//Something should happen here
```

with

```
completionHandler(json)
```

and call the function

```
getGenres() { json in 
    print(json)
}
```

Notes:

The check `guard let responseData = data else` is redundant and it will never fail. If `error` is `nil` then `data` is guaranteed to have a value.

You should print the caught `error` rather than a meaningless literal string.